# How to use from EnterpriseLibrary Validation Instead DataAnnotations Attribiute in mvc ajax form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, enterprise-library

I have a model like this

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;

namespace MvcValidationTest.Models
{ 
    public class Person
    {

        [NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate = "FullName Is required!!!")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

When I use from Html.BeginForm() like this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName )
    </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

When i submit form and FullName is empty... ValidationMessage show to me.
But when I Use from Ajax.BeginForm() like this

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post" }))
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Person</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName )
    </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

When i submit form and FullName is empty... ValidationMessage does not show to me.